# users IP Address in C# to get GeoIP location using sitecore Geo IP service

Tags: geo-location

we are using Sitecore 9.1.1 with Sitecore JSS.

I was trying to get GeoIP location based on User's IP address.

```
var w = Sitecore.CES.GeoIp.Core.Lookups.LookupManager.GetWhoIsInformationByIp(ipAddress);
```

How can I get IP address of visitors like we get using `https://whatismyipaddress.com/` site.

I tried below but not getting expected IP Address.

```
1.
//while this gets the ip address of the visitor making the call
  HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
2.
//gets the ipaddress of the machine hitting your production server              
string ipAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]; 

if (ipAddress == "" || ipAddress == null)  
{                                     
  //gets the ipaddress of your local server(localhost) during development phase                                                                         
  ipAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];              
}
```

thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: since I'm going to use Sitecore GeoIP service. can sitecore API provide me IP address also?

Comment: I dont fully understand what you're looking for. You say   HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress returns the visitor's IP - isnt' that what you're after?

Comment: Check this post for more details on getting the client IP:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735350/how-to-get-a-users-client-ip-address-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

It can be accomplished in two steps:

1. You need to raise a request to Sitecore to activate the `Sitecore IP Geolocation service`. You can refer to Sitecore Documents for the same. [Set up Sitecore IP Geolocation](https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/101/sitecore-experience-manager/set-up-sitecore-ip-geolocation.html)
2. After that use the below code to get the `visitor IpAddress`:

```
if (Tracker.Current?.Interaction?.Ip != null)
 {
    string ipAddress = new IPAddress(Tracker.Current.Interaction.Ip).ToString();
 }
```

Now from the IpAddress you can fetch the rest of the details like Region, Country, Post Code, Longitude and Latitude, etc. You can find the code below:

```
var geolocation = Sitecore.CES.GeoIp.Core.Lookups.LookupManager.GetWhoIsInformationByIp(ipAddress);
        if (geolocation != null)
        {
            var city = geolocation.City;
            var postCode = geolocation.PostalCode;
            // other details
        }
```

See the blog post: [Sitecore Geolocation Service API](https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2021/09/sitecore-geolocation-api.html)